# codeigniter rest library by phil sturgeon

Tags: codeigniter

What's the difference between **Phil Sturgeon's codeigniter REST Server** and normal **codeigniter** that you download from **codeigniter** site?

What new files are added to rest server?

If I have my code in codeigniter all ready, what files do I need to import from codeigniter rest server to my installed codeigniter and what changes are required?

My guess is only these two files needs to be imported in my codeigniter from the phil sturgeon's rest server.

```
application/libraries/Format.php
application/libraries/REST_Controller.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You may check http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/ for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You also need the config/rest.php file.